# Add additional metadata to a file for Search Server

Tags: asp.net, search, sharepoint-2010, metadata

Search Server is indexing all meta data for html documents through meta tags. For other file types such as Word documents, PDF's and so on the metadata is located in the file it self.

Let's say we have a CMS with meta data for each file located in a database, is it possible to add this data in any way?

I have tried adding metadata in the http headers through a httphandler, but Search Server doesn't index them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up servering the crawler a html page instead of the file, by hooking up a http module and the check the useragent string. The html page contained the text excerpt from the file and additional metadata in meta tags. I used IFilters to extract the content from the files.